# Override Material UI Button Text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UI button defaults the text within the button to uppercase. I want to override the text with the button to be the same as I have typed and not be uppercase.

I have tried to override the styling by using texttransform - none

```
viewButton: 
{ 
backgroundColor: "#00D2BC",
radius: "3px",
color: "#FFFFFF",
texttransform: "none"
}

<Button
 className={classes.viewButton}
 data-document={n.id}
 onClick={this.handleView}
>
   View Document
</Button>
```

Can anyone help with this.

Thanks

Comment: textTransform should be camel-cased.

Comment: This is not the recommended way to modify material-ui Components.

Each component in material-ui expose api to the elements and enable you to pass specific classes to modify the style.

in your case as @Smarticles101 mention - the button class that you should override is the "label" class.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The only problem I see with the code in your question is that you have "text**t**ransform" instead of "text**T**ransform".

This aspect of the buttons is controlled by the theme ([here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createTypography.js#L9), [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createTypography.js#L68), and [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L13)) so it is also possible to change this via the theme. I have demonstrated both approaches in the code below.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  makeStyles,
  createMuiTheme,
  MuiThemeProvider
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  button: {
    textTransform: "none"
  }
});
const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    button: {
      textTransform: "none"
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <Button>Default Behavior</Button>
      <Button className={classes.button}>Retain Case Via makeStyles</Button>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Button>Retain Case Via theme change</Button>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit button textTransform]

---

Here's a similar example but for v5 of Material-UI:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(`
  text-transform: none;
`);
const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const theme1 = createTheme({
  typography: {
    button: {
      textTransform: "none"
    }
  }
});
const theme2 = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textTransform: "none"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <Button>Default Behavior</Button>
      <StyledButton>Retain Case Via styled</StyledButton>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme1}>
        <Button>Retain Case Via theme change</Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme2}>
        <Button>Retain Case Via alternate theme change</Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit button textTransform]

Comment: Typescript kept throwing an error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TextTransform | TextTransform[] | undefined'`. So I silenced it with `textTransform:"capitalize" as any,` anyone know how to use it with typescript?

Comment: @Tittoh I don't get any issues with TypeScript: https://codesandbox.io/s/button-texttransform-typescript-y6m4ms.

Answer (score 10):

For those who don't wanna go an do this everywhere inside each components try global ovverrides,

```
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiButton: {
            root: {
                textTransform: 'none'
            }
        }
    },
});
```

You make a theme object like so, and provide it to the theme provider which should wrap your app component in the index.js file

```
<ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
    </PersistGate>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Imports:

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Answer (score 9):

Per the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css), you should use the `label` class to override the `text-transform` property:

Use this style:

```
viewButtonLabel: { textTransform: "none" }
```

With this button:

```
<Button
  className={classes.viewButton}
  data-document={n.id}
  onClick={this.handleView}
  classes={{ label: classes.viewButtonLabel }}
  >
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried Implementing using the class as you suggest and it doesnt work. I will read the material ui documentation again.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to work with V5

```
<Button sx={{ textTransform: 'none' }}>
Label
</Button>
```

https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

Answer (score 2):

I used Typography without playing with stying!

```
<Button>
  <Typography style={{ textTransform: 'none' }}>Test Button</Typography>
</Button>
```

Comment: In MUI V5, you should use `sx` instead of `style`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { createTheme, ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material/styles'

const defaultTheme: ThemeOptions = {
  typography: {
    button: {
      textTransform: 'none',
    },
  },
}

export const lightTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
    primary: {
      main: '#ff2449',
      light: '#ff6675',
      dark: '#c40022',
    },
  },
  ...defaultTheme,
})
export const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    primary: {
      main: '#f93c5b',
      light: '#ff7588',
      dark: '#bf0032',
    },
  },
  ...defaultTheme,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Shamseer Ahammed provided the clue that finally solved this problem for me.

The use of the "overrides" property in the custom theme finally did the trick for me. I've spent days trying to do this with MuiTab instead of Button. I THINK this is the heuristic:

1. Use "overrides" in my theme to specify that I want to customize components
2. Use the component name (`MuiButton` or `MuiTab`) to specify a component to customize
3. Provide a `key:value` pair for the customization (`textTransform: 'none'`).

I really wish the material-ui docs would make usage patterns like this more clear. I'd like there to be a middle-ground between trivial `HelloWorld` examples and the `Component API` nitty-gritty.

At least for me and my purposes, the answer from Shamseer Ahammed opened the door to my solution in a way that accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 0):

The MUI text transformation really sucks

I ended up changing the transformation for all the components which works great for me.

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      textTransform: "none",
    },
  },
});


<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>....</ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this long answer i will suggest a short answer

```
<Button>
     <span style={{textTransform: 'none'}}>View Document</span>
</Button>
```